# How to pass value to AutoMapper Profile projection?

Tags: entity-framework-core, automapper

We have a view of a list of support tickets.

We now have the requirement to show an additional icon, if the current logged in user has replied to a support ticket.
This means we have to add an additional property to our projection, we cannot just filter on the list of the current user.

Now our idea is to map this additional property with the profile. But we have no idea how we can pass the current user id to the profile.

At the and it could look like this

```
public class SupportTicketProjectionProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public SupportTicketProjectionProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<SupportTicketEntity, SupportTicketProjection>()
            .ForMember(p => p.CurrentUserHasReplied, 
               opt => opt.MapFrom(e=>e.Editors.Any(editor=> editor.Id == **passedIdValue**))
```

But how to pass the userId?

We found we can pass a Dictionary<string, object> to the ProjectTo method. Bot we cannot find any documentation how to access this dictionary in the AutoMapper profile.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the trick: create a temporary mapping model.

```
public class SupportTicketUserContextExpressionModel
{
    public SupportTicketEntity SupportTicket { get; set; }
    public bool UserHasReplied { get; set; }
}
```

With the help of the (lets name it) expression model you can inject additional sub-query results:

```
var query = _dbContext.SupportTickets
    .Select(ticket => new
    {
        ticket,
        hasReplied = ticket.Editors.Any(e => e.UserId == userId)
    })
    .Select(temp => new SupportTicketUserContextExpressionModel
    {
        SupportTicket = temp.ticket,
        HasReplied = temp.hasReplied
    }));
```

Now you need a new additional profile:

```
CreateMap<SupportTicketUserContextExpressionModel, SupportTicketUserView>()
     .ForMember(p => p.TicketId,
         opt => opt.MapFrom(e => e.SupportTicket.Id))

     // more here

     .ForMember(p => p.UserHasReplied,
         opt => opt.MapFrom(e => e.HasReplied));
```

And at the and you can use the profile for your ProjectTo:

```
.ProjectTo<SupportTicketUserView>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
```

Thanks, Ben!

Comment: Always nice to receive -1 for a working solution without any comment. ♥

Comment: I got -1 for mine answer as well, guess someone was just angry

Comment: +1 to both of you. Clever use of an intermediary dto when I couldn't get multiple parameters to work using the IQueryable projectto extension

Answer (score 4):

### Map

You can use resolution context dictionary, you pass when mapping objects. This is is much more difficult to maintain and debug than just assigning a filed after the mapping. If there will be new fields outside source class assigned you can also consider creating two mappings for 2 source classes. That being said here's the code:

Mapping class:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Src, Dest>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Param
        , opt => opt.ResolveUsing((src, dest, destMember, resContext)
            => src.Param = resContext.Items["item"]));
```

You can also pass the dictionary to nested objects mapping as. Mapper object and dictionary is accessible via resolution context.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Src, Dest>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Param
        , opt => opt.ResolveUsing((src, dest, destMember, resContext)
            => resContext.Mapper.Map<NestedDestClass>(src, opts =>
                {
                    opts.Items["item"] = resContext.Items["item"];
                }
            )));
```

Mapping objects

```
var dto = Mapper.Map<Dest>(item, 
    opts => opts.Items["item"] = "somevalue");
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5uIoKv)

### ProjectTo

You can use dictionaries when working with ProjectTo mappings. To do that you have to specify mapping definition where we create a runtime parameter, then at execution time when we supply it.

To create the mapping definition with a runtime parameter, we “fake” a closure that includes a named local variable. We can’t access the “real” value we’d use during execution in our configuration, so we create a stand-in that still creates a closure for us. The underlying expression tree that gets built recognizes this external input and creates a placeholder parameter to be supplied at runtime.

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
    string name = null;
    cfg.CreateMap<Dest, Source>()
        .ForMember(m => m.CurrentUserName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => name))
    ));
```

When executing the projection, we can supply our parameter value with a dictionary (example with annonymus object is available in [documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#parameterization) )

```
data.ProjectTo<OrderLineDTO>(configuration, new Dictionary<string, object> {["name"] = "test"}).ToList();
```

When the projection is executed by the underlying LINQ provider, the correct runtime value is replaced in the expression, letting you use per-map runtime values in your projections. You can use these runtime values in any configuration option that works off an expression

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is exactly what I've found (and dont like, because hard to maintain). Is there no other way to pass dynamic expressions (in my case ID compare) to the projection?

Comment: I don't think so, I recommend just doing `var dto = Mapper.Map<Dest>(item); dto.Image = image;`. It's easier to debug and unit tests should make sure the fileds are always assigned

Comment: I work with projections. If I use an isolated assigment, this would mean my query would be excecuted O(n)

Comment: I could solve my issue by create an multi-query (https://dotnetfiddle.net/BTzVOl) but I dont have any idea how to use now the multi-query result with ProjectTo. ProjectTo only works against an IQueryable Collection of given entity; no idea how to handle this without Map (I dont want to use Map, I want the benefit of ProjectTo).

Comment: did you look at [parametrization](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#parameterization), it's basically the same as with Map

Comment: let me update my anwser with a code snippet you can use and some explanation

Comment: I found the solution, see my answer :-) Thanks for your help!